# Unable to identify element in Selenium

Tags: html, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify text. Tried the following xpaths but still it shows unable to identify element error.

1. `//*[@id='bodyPartList_1']/li[1]/div`
2. `//div[@id='question_1_5' and contains(@span,'Does the patient weigh over 350lbs?')]`

HTML source for the element:

```
<div id="question_1_5" class="qaContainer">
    <input type="hidden" name="questionIds[]" value="5"/>
    <div class="left" style="width: 680px;">
    <span class="num">1.</span>
    <span class="ans" style="width: 650px;">                                                     
                               Does the patient weigh over 350lbs?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you paste your code and stack trace?

Comment: Please show HTML code that matches your XPaths (where is `bodyPartList_1` and `li`?), also show your stacktrace and full exception message. Btw, your second XPath is not correct.

Comment: The text `Does the patient weigh over 350lbs?` is a child of `<span class="ans" style="width: 650px;">`. Also in your HTML source the `<div class="left" style="width: 680px;">` does not get closed. Please post correct HTML.

Comment: Is this text residing inside a frame?

Comment: No, there is no frame.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 is missing the relevant html.
In part two the contains function takes two parameters, both of which must be strings.

```
//div[@id='question_1_5' and contains(span[2]/text(),'Does the patient weigh over 350lbs?')]
```

I'm assuming that the missing end div is on line 3.

Comment: No, it is not working. It shows the Error : FAIL Object not found Unable to locate element

Comment: have you added the end div?